# ¿Cuál es la opción para que un modal no se cierre con la tecla ESCP? Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap, typescript

Con estas opciones configuro inicialmente el modal.

```
configBackdrop = {
    animated: true,
    keyboard: true,
    backdrop: true,
    class: 'modal-lg',
    ignoreBackdropClick: true,    
};
```

Y así lo muestro desde mi código typescript.

```
this.modalNuevo = this.modalService.show(modalTemplate, this.configBackdrop);
```

Comment: Y si cambias a `keyboard: false`?...

Answer (score 0):

## Causa

Como indica en la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#options) la opción `keyboard: true` activa el cierre del modal con la tecla escape. Por lo tanto, seteando `keyboard: false`, desactivas ese comportamiento

## Ejemplo

```js
configBackdrop = {
    animated: true,
    keyboard: false,
    backdrop: true,
    class: 'modal-lg',
    ignoreBackdropClick: true,    
};

var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), configBackdrop);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```